# How do I finish this html code for custom browser New Tab?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, tabs

Someone I know was browsing the web and every time they opened a new tab it opened a completely blank homepage with the ability to type freely onto the newly opened page. Whatever they ended up typing they would press Enter and it would search just as if they had typed it in the Browsers address bar.

I asked them how they did that and they provided me with this code:

﻿    html { overflow:hidden; }     I tried to emulate what they did by saving that as an html file and opening it with my browser but it would just open to a completely blank page and I didn't have the ability to type anything. So I think that when they gave me the code it was cutoff because of a character limit in the chat that we were using. Would anyone know how to finish this to be able to do what I described they did. I would like to replicate it for myself every time I open a new tab.

Thank you to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a text input the size of the entire page, and when you press enter, the window location should just be the content of the text input.

#### For a URL search

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = "https://" + text.value; 
  }
});
```

```css
html
{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
textarea
{
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  resize: none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <textarea autofocus id="text"></textarea>
</html>
```

#### For a Google search

```js
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener( "keypress", function( event ){
    if( event.keyCode === 13 )
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = "https://google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI( this.value );
    }
    
})
```

```css
html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#search {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>&#65279;</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id = "search" autofocus>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"> <title>&#65279;</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> <link href="favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /> <style type="text/css"> html { overflow:hidden; } </style> </head> <body> <div id="search"> <input id="search-field" type="text"

<<<THIS is what I was trying to post in the initial post. Didn't notice that the code didn't show. The code that you gave me doesn't google search

Comment: So you want a google search rather than a simple URL redirect.

Comment: I updated the post for the google search option